# How to save and close appointment without discard event in OWA using office-js

Tags: office-js, outlook-web-addins, outlook-web-app

appointment  can be saved in OWA as following . but it does not close automatically as send or save button click event in OWA appointment .

```
 Office.context.mailbox.item.saveAsync(function(result) {

    });
```

Answer (score 2):

In the saveAsync callback function, you can call [close](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/objectmodel/preview-requirement-set/office.context.mailbox.item#close) API to close the window.
Below example will save and upon successful save, close the compose window.

```
Office.context.mailbox.item.saveAsync(function(result) {
    if (result.status === Office.AsyncResultStatus.Succeeded)
        Office.context.mailbox.item.close();
});
```

Edit:
I do see that in Outlook Web application (OWA), a dialog to Discard event is being shown even after successful save operation, but the same works on Outlook Win32/Mac. This could possibly be an issue in OWA.

Comment: How can I invoke the     saveAsync function? I have an add-in, which creates an entity at the back end through a POST. This will be created in a draft mode initially and upon 'Save' ing the appointment, I need to POST the set of details from this pane to the backend to update it. Could you please help me , how I can invoke this function when I click 'Save' button?